# Optimize perl code

Tags: perl

I have to write to check array ref for more than 3 params. If the value is coming from an array then I have written a foreach loop for that, then chop that and assign to a new variable after concatenating pipe.

Code

```
if ( defined $args->{hotel} ) {
    if ( ref( $args->{hotel} ) eq "ARRAY" ) {
        foreach my $hotel ( @{ $args->{hotel} } ) {
            $hotel .= $hotel . "|";
        }
        chop($hotel);
        $args->{hotel_name} = $hotel;
    } else {
        $args->{hotel_name} = $args->{hotel};
    }
} else {
    $args->{hotel_name} = $hotel;
}
if ( defined $args->{country} ) {
    if ( ref( $args->{country} ) eq "ARRAY" ) {
        foreach my $country_name ( @{ $args->{country} } ) {
            $country_name .= $country_name . "|";
        }
        chop($country_name);
        $args->{country_name} = $country_name;
    } else {
        $args->{country_name} = $args->{country};
    }
} else {
    $args->{country_name} = $country_name;
}
if ( defined $args->{city} ) {
    if ( ref( $args->{city} ) eq "ARRAY" ) {
        foreach my $city ( @{ $args->{city} } ) {
            $city .= $city . "|";
        }
        chop($city);
        $args->{city_name} = $city;
    } else {
        $args->{city_name} = $args->{city};
    }
} else {
    $args->{city_name} = $city;
}
```

I want to write a function for this kind of work so that there will be no repetition of same code. Please help me; how can we do this in Perl?

Comment: Map a lambda over the array of properties?

Comment: i don't have any idea about this is there any other simple way so that we can optimize the code and remove the repetition

Comment: Doesn't `chop` (a precursor to the modern `chomp`) simply remove the last character from the argument, so if you've just added a trailing pipe, `chop` removes it.

Comment: Well, do you want to optimize or to remove repetition? Those are unrelated and potentially conflicting goals. The answer you accepted is slightly *slower* than your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
sub convert_to_name ($$) {  # ($value, $fallback_name)
    my ($value, $fallback_name) = @_;
    if (defined $value) {
        if (ref($value) eq 'ARRAY') {
            return join '|', @$value;
        } else {
            return "$value";
        }
    } else {
        return $fallback_name;
    }
}

$args->{'hotel_name'} = convert_to_name $args->{'hotel'}, $hotel;
$args->{'country_name'} = convert_to_name $args->{'country'}, $country;
$args->{'city_name'} = convert_to_name $args->{'city'}, $city;
```

Comment: `convert_to_name($args->{'hotel'}) // $hotel` would be better if 5.10 is available as it avoids generating the default when it's not needed, and it avoids copying it.

Comment: @ikegami: FYI, I rolled back your edit, because the stringification was intentional.

Comment: Bug: `return "$value"` needlessly makes a copy of `$value`. It can also damage all kinds of data. It should simply be `return $value;`. // Nit: `$fallback_name` is a rather poor name for default value. `$default` is more appropriate. // Nit: `convert_to_name` is rather poor name, seeing as the sub doesn't convert to a name. // Nit: What's the parens around `ref`'s args but not around `defined`'s?

Comment: @ikegami: I wrote this answer based on my understanding of what the OP is trying to do. Most of your "nits" are that you think the OP is trying to do something different, and the rest are simply that you prefer a different coding style than the one I prefer. You are welcome to post your own answer that is how you like.

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be some potential bugs in your code, the biggest centering around reusing variable names at lower scopes.

However, of course you can add an iteration loop to your code that would remove the need for 3 nearly identical sections.  The following does that by creating a intermediate hash data structure to relate field names to values.

Note: I also simplified the code by inverting the logic if your first if statement so that all ifs could be at the same level.  Additionally, it makes sense to use a `join` instead of rolling your own such functionality.

```
my %hash = (
    hotel   => $hotel,
    country => $country_name,
    city    => $city,
);

while ( my ( $field, $value ) = each %hash ) {
    if ( !defined $args->{$field} ) {
        $args->{"${field}_name"} = $value;

    } elsif ( ref( $args->{$field} ) eq "ARRAY" ) {
        $args->{"${field}_name"} = join '|', @{ $args->{$field} };

    } else {
        $args->{"${field}_name"} = $args->{$field};
    }
}
```

Also, if you're comfortable with the Conditional operator, this can be reduced further.  However, some would consider this too cluttered:

```
while ( my ( $field, $value ) = each %hash ) {
    $args->{"${field}_name"} = !defined $args->{$field}
        ? $value
        : ref( $args->{$field} ) eq "ARRAY"
        ? join( '|', @{ $args->{$field} } )
        : $args->{$field};
}
```